# Replacing strings in lua containing special characters

Tags: string, replace, lua, substring, substitution

I want to replace string in lua. Here is the string.

```
strng='\begin{matrix}   1 & 2 & 3 \\    4 & 5 & 6 \\    7 & 8 & 10 \end{matrix}'
```

I want to replace

```
\begin{matrix} by {{
& by ,
\\ by },{
\end{matrix} by }}
```

I also want to remove all spaces. So the output will be

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,10}}
```

I have written the following function to do this.

```
function tempsubst(m1)
m1 = matrixprint(m1)
if type(m1) ~="string" then  return  m1 end
m1 = string.gsub(m1,"\begin%{matrix%}","{{" )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,"\\","},{" )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%&","," )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,"end%{matrix%}","}}" )
m1= string.gsub(m1 , "%s+", "")
return m1
end
```

This sometimes work but sometimes it does not work. There must be  mistakes in the function. I am newbie to lua. Could the code be corrected? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sometimes it does not work  is not the best problem description. provide example inputs and outputs.

Comment: If input is passed from some other function, it gives unexpected output. tempsubst(strng) works but tempsubst(somefunction(x)) doesn't work. Note that somefunction(x) gives string as output. I think apostrophe may be causing the problem.

Comment: All backslashes inside `"literal string"` must be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

When confused with escapes and backslashes, it's better to use long strings, which don't interpret those:

```
m1=[[\begin{matrix}   1 & 2 & 3 \\    4 & 5 & 6 \\    7 & 8 & 10 \end{matrix}]]
print(m1)
m1 = string.gsub(m1,[[\begin{matrix}]],"{{" )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,[[\\]],"},{" )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,[[&]],"," )
m1 = string.gsub(m1,[[\end{matrix}]],"}}" )
m1= string.gsub(m1 , [[%s+]], "")
print(m1)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to convert m1='\begin{matrix}   1 & 2 & 3 \\    4 & 5 & 6 \\    7 & 8 & 10 \end{matrix}' to m1=[[\begin{matrix}   1 & 2 & 3 \\    4 & 5 & 6 \\    7 & 8 & 10 \end{matrix}]]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your strings contain two escape sequences `"\b"` and `"\e"`.

I suppose you mean `"\\b"`? Escape each backslash!

Then you have the problem that you replace `"\\"` at any position with `"},{"`.
But at `"\\end"` you don't want that.

Because of that, after fixing the escape problem you get this output:

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,10},{}}
```

So either replace `\\end`s first or change the other pattern so it won't affect `"\\end"`

**Edit:**
if you get a string from outside like

> \\

your pattern is `"\\\\"` as you have to create a literal string with 2 backslashs which requires you to escape both, resulting in four backslashs. This pattern matches two backslash characters in a string.

Comment: I am still not able to get. Hope I will understand.

Comment: @Maths89 what is it you don't get?

Comment: I can't have string with \\b as it is output from some other function. I don't want ready made code but as code length is not too long, could you provide working solution?

Comment: @Maths89 well I just used your example. if the string comes form outside you still lack backslashs in your patterns.

Comment: So there is no solution to the problem.

Comment: @Maths89 of course there is a solution. did you fix the patterns?

Comment: @Maths89 Are you trying to state that the function returns the string and it is improperly escaped? or at least inconsistently escaped, sometimes 2 \ sometimes \ ?