# Converting table string to actual table in lua

Tags: arrays, string, lua, lua-table

I have the lua string.

```
strng = '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,"9+i"}}'
```

I want to convert strng to table.I know the following solution.

```
strng = loadstring("return "..strng)()
```

This solution works when used on strng. However it fails when it is given input from some other function. What I mean is this.

```
strng = loadstring("return "..somefunction(x))()
```

Here somefunction(x) gives the string output as `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,"9+i"}}` . So it doesn't work in this case. I am seeking for general solution, not for this particular string. However the output will always be of same type( I mean table string).

Comment: Please provide an example of case in which it does not work and its output. It works just fine with a: `loadstring("return " .. (function () return "{{1, 2, 3}, {4}}" end)())()`

Comment: Traverse your whole table and replace all strings with evaluated results.

Comment: In combination with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215092/replacing-strings-in-lua-containing-special-characters), I guess: You have a string, you'll replace patterns in this string, so that it looks like a lua  table and then you want to convert the table string to a lua table.
So why you don't do some lua pattern matching and directly fill the values into a lau table?

Comment: `strng = loadstring("return "..somefunction(x))()` this code is correct; if it doesn't work, something's wrong with `somefunction`